# React: Not able to access the value of state variable and each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an errot: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop and If I am doing console.log(sTime) in Chart Provider component. Its showing NaN. I have to pass this value in ChartComponent.

This Chart provider component.

```
var React = require('React');
var ReactDOM = require('ReactDOM');
var Chart = require('react-google-charts').Chart;
vat ChartComponent = require('ChartComponent');
var ChartConfig = require('ChartConfig');
var date = new Date();

var LineChart = React.createClass({    
     getInitialState: function()
       {
           return ({
              eTime: date.getTime(),
              sTime: this.eTime - (60 * 1000 * range),
          });
      },
      onUpdate: function(){
          var _this = this;
          date = new Date();
          _this.setState({
          eTime: date.getTime(),
          sTime: this.eTime - (60 * 1000 * range)
          })

       },
     render: function () {
         var _this = this;
         var item = [];

     ChartConfig.cList.forEach(function(col, cindex) {
        col.wList.forEach(function(widget, windex) {
           console.log(_this.state.sTime);
           item.push ( <div>
                         <div key={"title_" + cindex + windex} >
                         <div> widget.title </div>
                         </div>
                           <div key={"chart" + cindex + windex} >
                      <ChartComponent width="500px" height="400px"         
                        sTime={_this.state.sTime} 
                        eTime={_this.state.eTime} > 
                   </div>
               </div>
               );          
           });
         });

        return (
               <div >
                    {item}               
               </div>
        )
    }
  });   
  module.exports = LineChart;
```

ChartConfig.js file contains data:

```
module.exports = {
      cList : [ {
            widgetList : [ {
              title : "Average(Kbps)",
            }, {
              title : "Average DL(Kbps)",
            }, {
              title : "DL",

            } ],
            index : 0,
          }, {
            widgetList : [ {
              title : "Minutes",         
            }, {
              title : "Cell",        
            }, {
              title : "UL",      
            } ],
            index : 1,        
          } ],
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be here:

```
getInitialState: function() {
   return ({
      eTime: date.getTime(),
      sTime: this.eTime - (60 * 1000 * range),
  });
},
```

change to:

```
getInitialState: function() {
   return ({
      eTime: date.getTime(),
      sTime: date.getTime() - (60 * 1000 * range),
  });
},
```

looks like you are trying to use `this.eTime` in a few places but it is not a property directly on the component object but is a part of the components state object. Make sure you are always using `this.state.eTime` unless you did end up doing `this.eTime = something` which if its a value that is going to change it should be a part of state.

as for the keys error need to add a key value to the components that are being generated in your forEach loop like so:

```
col.wList.forEach(function(widget, windex) {
 console.log(_this.state.sTime);
 item.push ( <div key={windex}> // add unique key so react can check diff for performance
               <div key={"title_" + cindex + windex} >
               <div> widget.title </div>
               </div>
                 <div key={"chart" + cindex + windex} >
            <ChartComponent width="500px" height="400px"         
              sTime={_this.state.sTime} 
              eTime={_this.state.eTime} > 
         </div>
     </div>
     );          
 });
});
```

see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

but the basics are when you are using an iterator to generate JSX, you should add a unique key that way when react rerenders the component it will check to see if anything has changed based on the key. Otherwise when react rerenders, there is no unique key and react will assume it just needs to rerender the whole thing which is less performant.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that in one loop index variables are:

```
cindex == 1, windex == 10
// then key is
`title_110`
```

Now imagine that in other loop it is:

```
cindex == 11, windex == 0
// then key is
key == `title_110`
```

And that's a duplicate key. You should put between some delimiter, e.g.:

```
key={"title_" + cindex + "_" + windex}
```

However it is not a good practice to use array indexes as a component keys. It could cause bugs (for example when you shuffle array). You should use some business identifiers instead.

The problem with `NaN` is probably because in `getInitialState` method is `this.eTime` undefined value. So that:

```
undefined - (60 * 1000 * range) == NaN
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am not getting the error for each child in an array or iterator should have a unique “key” prop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little concerned with all the reassignments of _this = this, but that is for another conversation :-). Try changing this

```
  onUpdate: function(){
      var _this = this;
      date = new Date();
      _this.setState({
          eTime: date.getTime(),
          sTime: _this.eTime - (60 * 1000 * range)
      })

   },
```

also, look at your "getInitialState" function. You are referencing "this" in the context of !this..meaning, it is a different environ.

Answer (score 0):

finalfreq is correct that you aren't accessing state.stime correctly.

setstate()  only updates the state after a small amount of time has passed, so you can not access the updated state in code right after calling setstate.  You tried to access the new state before you had even finished calling setState (while making the object with {etime, stime}.

also:

you render after you have looped through ChartConfig.cList.forEach...

so they only update is when all the ChartConfigs are rendered at once. I think the time stamp on each one will be identical because they all access the same state.  (Check this using ReactInspector)

I'd recommend setting them up like this to get unique keys:

```
<ChartComponent width="500px" height="400px"         
    sTime={date.getTime()- (60 * 1000 * range)} 
    eTime={date.getTime()} >
```

This will probably give you unique keys

also, on a side note:  try to keep everything out of state, unless it absolutely has to be there.